# Login screen recording in JMeter repeating url issue

Tags: authentication, jmeter, recording

I need your help, I have recorded a login script in blaze meter and importing it into JMeter what I noticed that browsing URL is repeating like site.com/0, site.com/1,site.com/2 and so on. Please suggest what to do to fix it asap help required. thanks.

I am trying to record a login script in blaze meter when I imported the script in JMeter I found that the browsing URL is repeating. like example.com/0, example.com/1,and so on. please help me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

We cannot "help" without knowing what are your expectations.

When it comes to performance testing of web applications you need to ensure that [JMeter is properly configured to behave exactly like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

It means that JMeter should send the same requests and in the same manner as the real browser does.

In case if the network footprint generated by JMeter matches the one which the real browser produces - you don't need any "help" there. If it doesn't - we need to see:

- the dump of requests from "Network" tab of your [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)
- how did you configure the BlazeMeter Chrome Extension, i.e. choosing "Only top level requests" might "help" you

  [image]

Normally these numeric postfixes are used as the naming convention for the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to all nested [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), embedded resources and so on would be considered an integral part of the parent "transaction"